# Ruby mechanize clicking divs

Tags: ruby, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I'm trying to search a page for divs containing a specific class and then click on them. Each of these divs containing the class have a onclick event on them.

My current code looks like so,

```
home_page = agent.get('http://mysite.com')

home_page.search(".//div[@class='arrow up']").each do |i| 
  i.click
end
```

The div looks like so on the website.

```
<div class="arrow up" onclick="$(this).uparrow(u.config.places, null, event)" role="button" aria-label="uparrow" tabindex="0"></div>
```

Now there is obviously no click method for this because its a Nokogiri object, so I am here to ask is it possible for mechanize to click on a div like this? My current code can find all divs that match this class name, but I cannot figure out how to click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there's no way to do that. You need to look at the onclick attribute and try to figure out what it's doing. That or use Watir.

Comment: Yea after a bit of searching I found Watir. Was hoping I didnt have to load a browser to manipulate, but at least it's working.